# "bring up" versus "raise"

Tags: difference

Is there any situation/circumstance that a native speaker would differentiate between these?

My specific questions is traced back to the dictionaries such as Oxford, as there has been written that they are synonym.

> bring up
>
> raise

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In the "raise a question" sense, or the "raise a child" sense?

Comment: Note that pedantic/traditional speakers, especially of British English, may prefer _rear_ to _raise_.

Comment: This question may bring up a few eyebrows...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with many things, it's all about the context.  In a lot of circumstances "bring up" and "raise" are synonymous.

e.g. I might say

> I brought up 3 children

or

> I raised 3 children

and the meaning would be the same.

Or in a meeting:

> I would like to bring up an important issue

and

> I would like to raise an important issue

would be interchangeable.

However if I was a farmer I would almost certainly say

> I raise cattle and sheep

not

> I bring up cattle and sheep

For another example, from time to time my cat brings up furballs which I have to clean off the carpet.  I would not say my cat raises furballs, and if I did it certainly wouldn't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In general, they mean the same and are interchangeable. You can raise or bring up (or rear) a child, children, or a family.

We do differentiate the terms in some standard phrases:

*Let's get married and raise a family.*

*I was born and raised in California.*

Otherwise, they are synonyms, as well as the verb 'to rear', as in to rear children, to rear a family. 'To rear' may not be used as often as it once was, and it sounds kind of old fashioned.

You can also bring up or raise a question. But you don't rear a question. And in class you raise your hand to ask a question, you do not bring up your hand.

Answer (score 0):

- Since your question doesn’t specify any context, I should point out
  that “raise” is used in connection with things that can be expressed with numbers;
  e.g., “raise the quota”, “raise the price.”
- “Raising your voice” means “speaking louder”.
- It seems to me that “raise” works better than “bring up”
  in physical/mechanical/spatial contexts;
  e.g., “raise the flag,” “raise your hands,” “raise the bar.”
- … but “bring up” might be used by a speaker who is in an elevated location:
  “If you’re coming upstairs, bring up the dictionary.”

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add here some trainers believe that Raise is used when someone was born and raised in the same city/country/town e.g I was born and raised in Delhi.

However,if someone was born in one city/place but was brought up at some other place, we use brought up not raised.
e.g. He was born in Delhi but was brought up in Mumbai.